# Flask in Ubuntu - How to allow Flask to access a reserved file

Tags: apache, ubuntu, flask

I'd like Flask to be able to open the Apache error log (/var/logs/apache2/error.log) and show it to me in a reserved route. However the server does not like it as Flask does not have permission to read that file. The error is shown below:

```
with open('/var/log/apache2/error.log', 'r') as errorlog_file:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/apache2/error.log'
```

This is the Flask code:

```
@app.route('/errorlog', methods=['GET'])
def errorlog():    
    with open('/var/log/apache2/error.log', 'r') as errorlog_file:
        errorlog_text = errorlog_file.read()           
        return errorlog_text
```

What is the best workaround?

Edit:

For further info, I have the flask app in Digital Ocean on Ubuntu 14.04, deployed exactly according to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

The user that I use to do all the work has sudoer permissions and flask is in a virtualenv

Answer (score 2):

The user that runs the app doesn't have permission to view the file.  Ultimately, there is only one solution: change the permissions.  Either add the user that runs the Flask app to the group that can view the log file, or change the permissions on the log file so that others can read it.